# Increment in switch statement not working

Tags: arduino-mega

No matter how I rearrange this, the increment compare always returns false....

I have even taken it out of the if, and put it in its own if:

```
int buttonFSM(button *ptrButton)
{ 
    int i;
    i = digitalRead(ptrButton->pin); 
    switch(ptrButton->buttonState)
    {
    case SW_UP:
        if(i==0 && ++ptrButton->debounceTics == DBNC_TICS) //swtich went down
        {
            ptrButton->buttonState = SW_DOWN;
            ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
            return SW_TRANS_UD;       
        }
        ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
        return SW_UP;
    case SW_DOWN:
        if(i==1 && ++ptrButton->debounceTics == DBNC_TICS) //switch is back up
        {
            ptrButton->buttonState = SW_UP;
            ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
            return SW_TRANS_DU;       
        }
        ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
        return SW_DOWN;   
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the impression that `++ptrButton->debounceTics` needs some bracketing. I fear the compiler is reading it as `(++ptrButton)->debTic` and you actually mean `++(ptrButton->debTics)`. You are increasing `ptrButton`'s value, i.e. where it should point to, not the value of what it points to. I would also add some brackets to break up the if statement conditions, although I think that's more my preference than a syntax requirement: `if((i==0) && (++(ptrButton->debounceTics) == DBNC_TICS))`.

Comment: I'd go further and say that side effects like this in the expression statement  should be avoided for example:

ptrButton->debounceTics = ptrButton->debounceTics + 1; if (... expressions ...)

Comment: @Kolban The intention of the code is unclear, so it may be a requirement that it's written like this. [**Short circuit evaluation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) means that if `i!=0` (or `1` in the second `if` statement), *debounceTics will not be incremented*.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the path where the if doesn't happen are getting you. You don't show what DBNC_TICS is set to, but I'm assuming it's > 1.

ptrButton->debounceTics will never be greater than 1 because you always:

```
    ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
```

Comment: -1: the code is clearly a subroutine from `loop()` (or another function) so you cannot make assumptions on what `debounceTics`'s treatment ought to be inside this function.

Comment: Why is this marked down? This is the correct explanation.

Comment: @CharlieHanson No assumptions - it's always being set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to wrong expectations on operators precedence:
++ and -> have the same precedence, so they are evaluated left to right.
See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence .

Overall, the lack of parenthesis makes the readability poor.

The code can be improved by dropping the switch and simply checking that the current value is equal to the previous value through the duration of the sampling period.
Then read the value and decide if it's high or low.

But even this might be a poor choice, because it simply samples the value periodically and can miss changes that are not intercepted by the sampling.

Depending on the application, it might be preferrable (certainly it is more precise) to use interrupts on both edges (rising and falling) and a timeout: reset the timer at every interrupt. If the timer expires undisturbed, use the level read at the last interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

```C++
  if(i==0 && ++ptrButton->debounceTics == DBNC_TICS) //swtich went down
    {
        ptrButton->buttonState = SW_DOWN;
        ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
        return SW_TRANS_UD;       
    }
    ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
```

I'm going to agree with user3877595 but explain why, as his/her answer got a downvote.

`DBNC_TICS` has to be > 1, right? Otherwise what is the point?

We want to debounce after "x" ticks, and let's assume that the number of ticks is initially zero.

If `DBNC_TICS` is == 1 then this is always true:

```C++
++ptrButton->debounceTics == DBNC_TICS
```

Therefore that test is useless.

If `DBNC_TICS` > 1 then it will not execute the "if" block and execute this instead:

```C++
    ptrButton->debounceTics = 0;
```

So `ptrButton->debounceTics` is back to zero, and we are back to square 1.

Therefore the test will always be false.

> No matter how I rearrange this, the increment compare always returns false....

As stated in the question.